# What generates this message to update?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios

I'm on macOS Catalina 10.15.7 and iOS 14.1.  This AM when I connected my iPhone to Mac, I got this pop up.  It is not something I see re: regular updates - never gotten it before.  I just X'd through it and continued as usual. I recently synced the other week with all the same software and didnt get it.  Have not made any os or ios updates or changes to warrant message.  I did use the [Learn More](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208831) linkbut did not get any useful info from Apple other than then saying its needed to connect - which is is NOT as i X'd through it and was able to connect.  What is it for?  Whats it mean?  Anyone else get one?

[image: connection message]

Comment: Is your device called TiPhone?

Comment: What happens when you click the `Learn More...` button? It is there for a reason.

Comment: yes, TiPhone is the name.

Comment: well, i did hit the Learn More and its llike the secutirty updates, you click to get the info and they dont tell you anything but that its for security....    https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208831

Answer (score 3):

Not a definitive answer, but anecdotally…

It's happened on every Mac here that is linked to an iOS device, on first connect after 14.1/14.2 [we held off 14 for a while]
Why, idk, but yes, something changed [or is about to change once you do update to 14] in the phone/pad that needs a macOS/iTunes update.
No Catalina here, but his happened on both High Sierra & Mojave Macs. I had assumed, prior to your question, the it was because we weren't up to date on macOS itself, but it seems not to be the case.

Comment: yep, weird.  a day or so before i got this message, i had been syncing the iphone a few times to try to solve music playlist disappearing issue and didnt get the message then.  No updates to ios or os then started to get the message.....

Comment: Hey Tetsujin - what happened after you did the update?  I connected my phone just now and got the prompt again.  Apple told me its an option to update to bigsur

Comment: Life went on as normal. None of the Macs here are capable of running Catalina, so idk what would happen differently if they were.